# Network Manager doesn't have option of enable mobile broadband after upgrading 14.04 to latest linux image

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, network-manager, mobile-broadband

Earlier mobile broadband connection seems to work flawlessly but after Upgrading trusty tahr 14.04.1 to linux image 3.13.0-35 there seems to be problem.

First it started popping for USB modem password.

when tried to start it all over again by deleting the connection. network manager doesn't show the mobile broadband option.

lsusb shows the device.

Let me know which module is missing and need to be downloaded.

Comment: what is your 3g/4g stick brand ?

Comment: reinstall `NetworkManager` using `apt`.

Comment: You will have to use an older kernel and file a bug report. Re-installing NetworkManager is unlikely to resolve your problem.

Comment: execute this command in the terminal: `sudo service mobile-broadband-connect start` or first do the stop (`sudo service mobile-broadband-connect stop
`) and then start. Then get the status by: `sudo service mobile-broadband-connect status`

Comment: @bodhi.zazen- tried to switch older kernel didn't solved the problem but got a work around got new installation of 14.04.1 beside older one so once USB get detected in that version switch(restart) over to new version. May it help someone. In meantime will try to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this thread solved the problem of not detecting modem by Network Manager.

[Huawei E3272 Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/525965/huawei-e3272-ubuntu)

Its adding rule for your Vendor and Productid if it gets detected in lsusb.